# Rails model - change true to yes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My model contains some boolean columns which return true or false. e.g. `is_value` has either a 1 or a 0.

```
MyModel.all
```

Is there a way of converting the `is_value` in the above line of code, or through a scope, such that true and false are converted to yes/no?

It is possible when calling a model?

Comment: This sounds like something that belongs in your view layer - view helpers, presenters, decorators etc. not something I'd concern myself with in the model. Perhaps you could elaborate on your use case?

Comment: I need to pass an activerecord object to a helper method but I cannot modify the helper method (don't ask!).  So I need to send the ActiveRecord object with the values already in place.

Comment: you should use a decorator to convert to yes/no pair, not in a model. All the quesries shoul use true/false values

Comment: What do you mean by 'converted to yes/no'? Do you want true to become a string 'yes' and false to become a string 'no'? If `is_value` is a table column, then it cannot change its type.

Comment: I guess its not possible, perhaps a misunderstanding of what an activerecord object is on my behalf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fetch and override the `is_value` method on the returned records. This would be ok if you are only fetching the records for display purposes and you know that `is_value` won't be used in any other context.

```
module TrueToYes
  def is_value
    super ? "Yes" : "No" # Assuming is_value on MyModel is a boolean
  end
end

# For a collection
decorated_models = MyModel.all.map{|model| model.extend(TrueToYes) }
decorated_models.first.is_value # => 'Yes'

# Single Record
my_model = MyModel.first
my_model.is_value # => true
my_model.extend(TrueToYes)
my_model.is_value # => 'Yes'
```